# Endogeneity without correlation?

Tags: regression, correlation, instrumental-variables

Is it, in general, possible that two variables are endogenous even if they are not correlated with each other at all?

Comment: I constructed an index, consisting of x1 and x2. Denote it as x3. People in seminars are now concerned whether the index x3 is endogenous to y - mainly because x1 may drive y. However, neither x1 and the index x3 are strongly correlated (correlation is 0.08), nor is x1 strongly correlated with y. Can we thus say that x1 does not cause endogeneity of x3 with respect to y?

Answer (score 5):

Your question is bit confusing. The answer is Yes. It is possible that two variables are endogenous even if they are not correlated with each other at all.

Consider the model $Y = a +bX_1+cX_2 +e$. We can construct variables  where $Cov(X_1,X_2)=0$, but $Cov(X_1, e)$ and $Cov(X_2,e)$ are non zero.

Here is the example in R:

```
x1= rnorm(1000); 
x2 =rnorm(1000); 
x3= 0.2*x1+ 0.3*x2 + 0.4*rnorm(1000); 
e=0.1*rnorm(1000); 
y=3+2*x1+3*x2+x3+e;
```

Here $x_3$ is the omitted variable, which makes $x_1$ and $x_2$ endogenous. $Cov(x_1,x_2) =0$ by construction and $Cov(x_1,x_3+e)$ and $Cov(x_2,x_3+e)$ are nonzero.

Answer (score 1):

The image below (from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence)) shows examples of dependence and correlation. Of particular interest here is the last row of images. Some of them are clearly related but have zero correlation. Why? Because correlation is a measure of **linear dependence**. Variables can be related in a multitude of non-linear ways, like the ones in the image.

[image]